# Fire block help (picture included)

Tags: framing, basement-refinishing

Basement has been framed but here is what I'm looking at. I have a 2x6 exterior wall that has a 38" cinder block half wall protruding 1 1/2" from the framed wall above it. I framed that out for a 5" shelf to come down the line.

The area above that wall to upstairs floor is 84" and has been insulated with a vapor barrier by builder. I will need to install blocking on the front side of those 2x6s parallel to the ceiling joists to fasten ceiling rock to.

Does that area behind that 2x4 blocking need to have fire block? 2x6s installed into each bay parallel to the 2x4 blocking?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I gave up on following the word about halfway through. Maybe you could do a quick hand sketch and upload a picture of it?

Comment: As always, thanks for the quick reply! Edited OP with picture attached.

Comment: "*parallel to the ceiling joists*" ? Concerning the wall on the right side, Why not just run a 2x4 ledger board across the wall on top of the vapor barrier to match the joist height ?

Comment: My plan is to run a 2x4 on the face of wall parallel to the joists, sorry if it's worded poorly. My question is moreso what sort of fire block will then need to be installed on the backside of that ledger? Cut open the barrier and install 2x6s in the bays?

Comment: I think I'll just go ahead and do that. Someone give me the go ahead. 